# How to integrate CAPTCHA on register page?

Tags: user-registration, captcha

How can I integrate CAPTCHA on my register page to prevet bots to register (to prevent them from submiting the form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may search install a pluggin like [No CAPTCHA](http://wpplugindirectory.org/anti-spam-by-cleantalk-no-captcha/).

Supports: Contact Form 7, Ninja Forms, Gravity Forms, MailChimp, Formidable forms, WooCommerce, JetPack comments and contact form, BuddyPress, bbPress, Fast Secure Contact form, S2Member, MailPoet, any WordPress registrations & contact forms and themes.